# OpenMP Runtimes

Tags: openmp, riscv32

Can anyone recommend a compiler and runtime that will support OpenMP and OpenMP offload on RISC-V processors? I am not interested in running Linux on the RISC-V processors due to overhead and am seeking a much lighter weight runtime implementation that will support all OpenMP features.

Also, is there a list of runtime primitives that are required to support OpenMP? Where can this information be found? For example, the underlying thread and memory manipulation services.

Need documentation and recommendations.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but you should specify which OS you are using or want to use, if not Linux.

Comment: BTW I don't don't get why Linux doesn't do? There exists many Linux distributions, including lightweight ones, some that are designed for Real Time, etc... Don't know what is available for Risc-V, though

Comment: What is the exact subset of OpenMP that you will need?

Comment: The host processor will be running Linux. The offload RISC-V processors will be running either an existing low overhead runtime that will support OpenMP Offload, or if it does not exist, a low overhead runtime will need to be created for the offload RISC-V processors. I would like to implement the majority of OpenMP offload functionality   I have purchased and read the book “High Performance Parallel Runtimes” by Michael Klemm. In this book, TBB was used to provide the threads and thread pools. The authors of this excellent book strongly discourage creating your own runtime system.